# Call a method when fragment is visible to user

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need execute a method when the fragment is visible (to the user).

Example:
I have 2 buttons (button 1 and button 2) ,
2 fragments(fragment 1 and fragment 2)
and the method `loadImages()` inside the class fragment 2.

when I press "button2" I want to replace fragment 1 by fragment 2
and then after the fragment 2 is visible (to the user) call `loadImages()`.

I tried to use `onResume()` in the fragment class but it calls the method before the fragment is visible and it makes some delay to the transition.

I tried `setUserVisibleHint()` too and did not work.

A good example is the Instagram app. when you click on profile it loads the profile activity first and then import all the images.

I hope someone can help me. I will appreciate your help so much. Thank you.

Comment: `onResume()` is called well after the `Activity` is visible and you are supposed to load the images in `onViewCreated()` in the `Fragment`. Whatever you are doing wrong, it has to do with something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by what you are trying to do. It sounds like the images are loading too fast for you... so does that mean that you have the images ready to display? And that is a bad thing?

My guess (and this is just a guess) is that Instagram does not have the profile pictures in memory, so they have to make an API call to retrieve them, which is why they show up on a delay. If the same is the case for you, consider starting an `AsyncTask` in the `onResume` method of the fragment. Do whatever loading you need to do for the images in the background, and then make the images appear in the onPostExecute callback on the main thread. Make sure you only start the task if the images are not already loaded.

However, if you already have the images loaded in memory, and you just want a delay before they appear to the user, then you can do a `postDelayed` method on `Handler`. Something like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadImages();   
    }
}, 1000);
```

**Edit**

As [kcoppock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321697/kcoppock)  points out, the handler code is pretty bad. I meant it to be a quick example, but it is so wrong I should not have included it in the first place. A more complete answer would be:

```
private Handler handler;

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(handler == null){
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loadImages();   
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}

public void onDestroyView(){
    super.onDestroyView();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    handler = null;
}
```

Comment: You have to be careful using Runnables to interact with the UI. Keep a reference to the Handler and make sure to call `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` to remove any pending messages in `onDestroyView()` (in case your Fragment goes away before your Runnable actually executes).

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the right answer. And the problem was not are loading too fast. Think about you have 2 tabs when you are in the first one and click the 2nd one it freeze up in the first one until all images are loaded and the go to tab 2 instead load tab 2 and then import images.

Comment: @user2643881 Make sure to check out my edit so you don't introduce a bad race condition.

Comment: @user2643881 It sounds like you're loading images on the UI thread, and that's your real problem. You should offload your image loading to a background thread and only display them after loading completes. There are some good libraries to help handle this (see Picasso).

Comment: Sure the handler makes the app crash when I change from portrait to landscape or vice versa. There is some way to fix it? i tried
 @Override
 public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
   handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
      handler = null;
 }
But did not work.

Comment: @user2643881 I would probably need to see a stacktrace to help with that crash... But I'm in agreement with kcoppock. It sounds like you are doing some sort of heavy processing on the main thread. You should move that to a background thread. Look into `AsyncTask`, or a third party library.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ViewTreeObserver` callbacks:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
    final View view = v;

    // Add a callback to be invoked when the view is drawn
    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDraw() {
            // Immediately detach the listener so it only is called once
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnDrawListener(this);

            // You're visible! Do your stuff.
            loadImages();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#removeOnDrawListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener)) for `removeOnDrawListener` specifically states that it shouldn't be called in `onDraw`. It can cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onActivityCreated() callBck

Comment: that is still called before the view is visible

Comment: I did it is the same Result. Instead detach fragment 1 and show fragment 2 then call callImages();

It calls all the images, and then when fragment 2 is showed it has all the images.